# Thread doesn't start on Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have this piece of code into a ListFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  postTitleList);
   setListAdapter(aa);

   Thread syncThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run()
       {
           syncPosts();
       }
   });
   syncThread.start();

   Log.d("POSTS", "Thread Status: " + syncThread.getState().toString());
   Log.d("POSTS", "Thread ID: " + Long.toString(syncThread.getId()));
}
```

but unfortunately the Thread never starts, it remains in WAITING status, is there a way to force it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is running.  It is most likely getting into a `WAITING` state because something in `syncPosts()` is waiting on something.  `WAITING` is the state you get when you are doing some `object.wait();` and is waiting for someone to `notify()` it.

If you show some of the `syncPosts()` code we should be able to help you find the place where the thread is stuck.

Comment: here you are the entire ListFragment code http://pastie.org/7729526, obviously I've replaced the real rss feed with a dummy one, you can use any RSS feed Url

Comment: I suspect it is something in the http connection code.  You might try commenting code out until the wait goes away @user1895405.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of Log.d(), I found the problem: it was on line 58

```
if(child.getNodeName() == "title")
```

changing this line to

```
if(child.getNodeName().equals("title"));
```

everything works fine